# Passing values List as parameter a function

Tags: java, reflection

Im working on a Java class by using reflection, I have a list of different type of objects:

```
public List<Object> MethodSignatureObjects
```

and, I need to invoke a method by using the folowing logic:

```
   Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
   Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("method name", parameterTypes)
   method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, params)
```

Is there any way to put the objects contained on MethodSignatureObjects on getDeclaredMethod, I mean, something like this:

```
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod (methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
```

where parameters1 , parameters2, parameter n.... come from   MethodSignatureObjects

I really appreaciate any advise.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please show the actual signature of the method that you're trying to invoke.

Comment: Please make sure that when you post lines of code, you indent at least 4 spaces or use the {} icon.  Your first line used a `List<Object>`, but StackOverflow didn't interpret it as code and then thought `<Object>` was an HTML tag, and it didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass a list but an array to the method

```
// List<Object> methodSignatureObjects

int size = methodSignatureObjects.size();
Class<?>[] asArray = new Class<?>[size];
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    asArray[i] = methodSignatureObjects.get(i).getClass();
}

Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("method name", asArray);
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, params)
```